# PLSQL FOR loop while executing CURSOR

Tags: plsql, cursor

I would like to know if there's any option to iterate a table while performing SELECT values into a CURSOR.

For example:
I have a table *TEMP_NUMBERS* which contains only numbers (single column).
I have to perform a SELECT from each number in the table (I do not know the amount of rows in the table in advance).

Here is basically what I'm attempting to do. Obviously this does not work, but can I do some kind of a workaround?
I need to SELECT the data into the **p_cv_PermsNotifs** which is a RETURN REF CURSOR.

```
IF NOT p_cv_PermsNotifs%ISOPEN THEN OPEN p_cv_PermsNotifs FOR

FOR i IN 1..TEMP_NUMBERS.NUMBER.COUNT LOOP
SELECT DISTINCT
    SEC_USER_ROLE.ENTITY_TYP_CODE,
    SEC_USER_ROLE.ENTITY_ID
FROM
    SEC_USER_ROLE
WHERE
    SEC_USER_ROLE.ENTITY_ID = i
END LOOP;

END IF;
```

Also tried this:

```
IF NOT p_cv_PermsNotifs%ISOPEN THEN OPEN p_cv_PermsNotifs FOR

SELECT DISTINCT
    SEC_USER_ROLE.ENTITY_TYP_CODE,
    SEC_USER_ROLE.ENTITY_ID
FROM
    SEC_USER_ROLE
WHERE
    SEC_USER_ROLE.ENTITY_ID IN
  (SELECT * FROM TABLE (lv_ListOfEntities))

END IF;
```

Where lv_ListOfEntities is table of NUMBER indexed by BINARY INTEGER.
But I'm getting **"ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to join your temporary table that holds the numbers to the sec_user_role table?

Answer (score 0):

In> Hey if you pass a single number at a time, everytime the refcursor

> will be overwritten by the next value. So at the end you will only get
>   the value for last number in the refcursor. A better way is to use
>   some basic PL/SQL Bulk COLLECT logic which will give you the desired
>   output.
>   Hope this helps

```
    --Creating sql type
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE lv_num_tab IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
--plsql block
var p_lst refcursor;
DECLARE
  lv_num lv_num_tab;
BEGIN
  SELECT COL1 BULK COLLECT INTO lv_num FROM TEMP_NUMBERS;
  OPEN p_lst FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT SEC_USER_ROLE.ENTITY_TYP_CODE,
    SEC_USER_ROLE.ENTITY_ID
  FROM SEC_USER_ROLE
  WHERE SEC_USER_ROLE.ENTITY_ID IN
    (SELECT * FROM TABLE(cast(lv_num as lv_num_tab))
    );
END;
```

Comment: Tried this solution, but I'm getting:
**ora-22905 cannot access rows from a non-nested table item**

Comment: Try this I have added a cast function just to ensure we do not get this error.